# Adjust the positioning of one element without affecting the others' in css

Tags: css

I have just begun exploring CSS and am looking forward to gain an in-depth understanding of the language.

One of the issues I'm facing with a project is the alignment of the products in mobile view.

Website - http://klcl.com.my/product-listing/

In the mobile view, the products are touching the right side of the screen. I want them to be centered. I tried adding a 'margin-right: 15px' and it works; however, that new line of code affects the social media icon in the footer as well. I'm guessing because both the product list and the icon are using the '.col-md-4' class tag.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="col-md-9 product-listing-main">
   <div class="row">
     <?php 
       $args = array(
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'post_type' => 'product'
       );
       $query = new WP_Query($args);
       while ($query->have_posts()) :
         $query->the_post();
       ?>
       <div class="col-md-4">
          <figure>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));?>" /></a>
          <figcation><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></figcation>
          </figure>
          </div>
         <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
      </div>
     </div>
```

How can I align the products to the middle without affecting any other elements on the website? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css to reset the previous settings:

```
  .on-social{margin-right:initial !important;}
```

or

```
  .on-social{margin-right:0px !important;}
```

please consider `margin: 0 auto;` for centering the elements.

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't seem to be working though. The social media button is still moving when I adjust the margin for '.col-md-4'.

Answer (score 0):

After a short look at your code i see that you are often manipulating the paddings of bootstrap elements (container, col-* …) and that leads to confusion. Try to avoid this and everything runs fine.